# Bootstrap horizontal form layout

Tags: 7, theming, forms

In Bootstrap there is a nice horizontal form option. But in Drupal + Bootstrap base theme I couldn't find any ways to use this horizontal forms and layout form elements as it described, eg. col-2 for labels and col-10 for inputs.

The only way I found is Strapped theme (https://www.drupal.org/project/strapped)  but it is in dev stage and I don't need one more base theme.

Bootstrap is so popular along with horizontal forms and I don't want to believe there is no way to solve this problem.

Or everybody uses `hook_form_alter()` and render horizontal form somehow in code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `hook_form_alter()` is the only way I can think of. I can't find module out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

Can you paste an example here with the code that didn't work for you?

Did you respect the structure below?

```
<div class="form-group form-item form-item-example-input form-type-textfield"> 
  <label for="edit-example-input" class="control-label col-md-2">Enter long URL: </label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <input type="text" maxlength="100" size="60" value="http://" name="example_input" id="edit-example-input" class="form-control col-md-10 form-text" tabindex="1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This example works, of course. I have seen it. But my question is there any UI to manage forms to be rendered as horizontal or inline or vertical.

Comment: 1. For sure, you can use CSS.

Comment: 2. You can use hook_form_alter() as you said.
3. You can try a module like https://www.drupal.org/project/arrange_fields if it is more simple for you.

Comment: In Drupal Bootstrap theme settings there is no choice of form type. And by default Bootstrap theme rendering form without classes .form-inline or .form-horizontal. How can we use these classes without hook_form_alter()?

Comment: I just imagine if there will be an option in theme settings or for each form to select form type. And Bootstrap theme render it automaticaly inline or in grid.

Comment: I don't think there is such an option. You need to use hook_form_alter to add the needed classes (if you really want to use Bootstrap for that).

Comment: -1 Not an answer, more a question / conversation.